# How to bind excel sheet to cascaded dropdown list in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, user-interface

Used below code to read excel sheet But it is giving Exception as **The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine**

Tried all possible solution from internet but none is working

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataSet temp_ds = new DataSet();
                temp_ds = ReadExcelFile();

                CheckBoxList1.DataSource = temp_ds.Tables[0];
                CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
            }


        }


        protected void Bindxml_To_chkboxlist(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filepath = Server.MapPath("Cust_input1.xml");
            using(DataSet DS = new DataSet())
            {

                DS.ReadXml(filepath);

                CheckBoxList1.DataSource = DS;
                CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "CustomerName";
                CheckBoxList1.DataBind();


            }
        }


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Response.Redirect("Add New WOS Customer.aspx");
        }




        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private string GetConnectionString()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            // XLSX - Excel 2007, 2010, 2012, 2013
            props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0";
            props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 14.0 XML";
            props["IMEX"] = "1";
            props["Data Source"] = @"C:\\Users\\amar.kate\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\input\\input.xlsx";

            // XLS - Excel 2003 and Older
            //props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            //props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 8.0";
            //props["Data Source"] = "C:\\Users\\amar.kate\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\WebApplication5\\WebApplication5\\input\\input.xls";

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
            {
                sb.Append(prop.Key);
                sb.Append('=');
                sb.Append(prop.Value);
                sb.Append(';');
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }

        private DataSet ReadExcelFile()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                DataTable dtSheet = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                // loop through sheet to get col name
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheet.Rows)
                {
                    string sheetName = dr["Sheet1"].ToString();
                    if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                        continue;

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
                    Response.Write(cmd.CommandText);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.TableName = sheetName;

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);

                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                }

                cmd = null;
                //conn.Close();

            }

            return ds;
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are literally tons of examples out there to get a start. One would be this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/976156

Comment: @LocEngineer I have used above code but not working

Comment: Take a good look at the article I linked. You don't want a full post-back every time the dropdown value has changed. What you want is an AJAX call to get the data without having to reload the page (and lose your combo index). Concering your OLEDB error, try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me atleast 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb